# Environment setup for testing website in different browser

Tags: linux, internet-explorer, web-applications, ubuntu, browser

Im developing a webapp and I need to test that webapp in different browser like in firefox, chrome and IE. Now my problem is how can I setup this kind of environment. I only have a linux ubuntu OS and the problem is how can I run the IE.

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to run IE on Ubuntu, you can try [IEs4Linux](http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page). But to run IEs4Linux, you need a valid Windows license. If you have a Windows license, then you should really install Windows in a [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) virtual machine and then run [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) inside it. IETester is a *great* tool for testing all the different IE versions.

As an alternative, you could request an [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) Windows instance and install any Windows software you need there, including IETester or any browser that you want to test under Windows. This does not require a Windows license, since Amazon provides it for you.

Either way, it is not permissible by the EULA that you run IE without having a Windows license.

Answer (score 1):

If your site is internet accessible, you can use a service like [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/)

You can also try to install IE on Linux using a Wine utility: http://www.danielgibbs.net/journal/installing-internet-explorer-6-ie6-on-linux-ubuntu

[playonlinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) also lets you test with IE